# JSON Decode failure Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I know this is the second time I've asked about JSON but I just can't figure out how it works. I keep getting errors because it can't load the data ... The JSON I'm using is a little more complex than the previous one

```
{
  "profile_v2": {
    "name": {
      "full_name": "test test",
      "first_name": "test",
      "middle_name": "",
      "last_name": "test"
    },
    "emails": {
      "emails": [
        "test@icloud.com"
      ],
      "previous_emails": [
        "test.50@facebook.com"
      ],
      "pending_emails": [
      ],
      "ad_account_emails": [
      ]
    },
    "birthday": {
      "year": 33,
      "month": 33,
      "day": 24
    },
    "gender": {
      "gender_option": "MALE",
      "pronoun": "MALE"
    },
    "previous_names": [
    ],
    "other_names": [
    ],
    "current_city": {
      "name": "test",
      "timestamp": 0
    },
    "hometown": {
      "name": "test",
      "timestamp": 0
    },
    "relationship": {
      "status": "",
      "timestamp": 1574556291
    },
    "education_experiences": [
      
    ],
    "work_experiences": [
      {
        "employer": "test test test test",
        "title": "test",
        "location": "test test test",
        "description": "",
        "start_timestamp": 1246442400,
        "timestamp": 1589226310
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Questo invece è il mio codice per decodificare i dati

```
private let JSONFriendFileName = "Profile"

extension Bundle {
    func decode<T: Decodable>(file: String) -> T {
        guard let url = self.url(forResource: JSONFriendFileName, withExtension: "json") else {
            fatalError("Non è stato possibile trovare il file \(file) in questo progetto. Verifica che il nome del file corrisponda a quello inserito nella funzione 'func decode<T: Decodable>(file: String) -> T' ")
        }
        
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
            fatalError("Non è stato possibile recuperare i dati contenuti nel file \(file) di questo progetto")
        }
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        
        guard let loadData = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
            fatalError("Non è stato possibile decodificare il file \(file) in questo progetto")
        }
        return loadData
    }    
}
```

---

This is the Manager class instead
I use **app.quicktype.io**

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome: Codable {
    var profileV2: ProfileV2

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case profileV2 = "profile_v2"
    }
}

// MARK: - ProfileV2
struct ProfileV2: Codable {
    var name: Name
    var emails: Emails
    var birthday: Birthday
    var gender: Gender
    var previousNames, otherNames: [JSONAny]
    var currentCity, hometown: CurrentCity
    var relationship: Relationship
    var educationExperiences: [JSONAny]
    var workExperiences: [WorkExperience]
    var bloodInfo: BloodInfo
    var websites: [JSONAny]
    var screenNames: [ScreenName]
    var phoneNumbers: [PhoneNumber]
    var registrationTimestamp: Int
    var profileURI: String
    var introBio: CurrentCity

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, emails, birthday, gender
        case previousNames
        case otherNames
        case currentCity
        case hometown, relationship
        case educationExperiences
        case workExperiences
        case bloodInfo
        case websites
        case screenNames
        case phoneNumbers
        case registrationTimestamp
        case profileURI
        case introBio
    }

static let root: ProfileV1 = Bundle.main.decode(file: "Profile.json")
static let infoUser: ProfileV2 = root.profileV2
}

// MARK: - Birthday
struct Birthday: Codable {
    var year, month, day: Int
}

// MARK: - BloodInfo
struct BloodInfo: Codable {
    var bloodDonorStatus: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case bloodDonorStatus
    }
}

// MARK: - CurrentCity
struct CurrentCity: Codable {
    var name: String
    var timestamp: Int
}

// MARK: - Emails
struct Emails: Codable {
    var emails, previousEmails: [String]
    var pendingEmails, adAccountEmails: [JSONAny]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case emails
        case previousEmails
        case pendingEmails
        case adAccountEmails
    }
}

// MARK: - Gender
struct Gender: Codable {
    var genderOption, pronoun: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case genderOption
        case pronoun
    }
}

// MARK: - Name
struct Name: Codable {
    var fullName, firstName, middleName, lastName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case fullName
        case firstName
        case middleName
        case lastName
    }
}

// MARK: - PhoneNumber
struct PhoneNumber: Codable {
    var phoneType, phoneNumber: String
    var verified: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case phoneType
        case phoneNumber
        case verified
    }
}

// MARK: - Relationship
struct Relationship: Codable {
    var status: String
    var timestamp: Int
}

// MARK: - ScreenName
struct ScreenName: Codable {
    var serviceName: String
    var names: [CurrentCity]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case serviceName
        case names
    }
}

// MARK: - WorkExperience
struct WorkExperience: Codable {
    var employer, title, location, description: String
    var startTimestamp, timestamp: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case employer, title, location, description
        case startTimestamp
        case timestamp
    }
}

// MARK: - Encode/decode helpers

class JSONNull: Codable, Hashable {

    public static func == (lhs: JSONNull, rhs: JSONNull) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    public var hashValue: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public init() {}

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encodeNil()
    }
}

class JSONCodingKey: CodingKey {
    let key: String

    required init?(intValue: Int) {
        return nil
    }

    required init?(stringValue: String) {
        key = stringValue
    }

    var intValue: Int? {
        return nil
    }

    var stringValue: String {
        return key
    }
}

class JSONAny: Codable {

    let value: Any

    static func decodingError(forCodingPath codingPath: [CodingKey]) -> DecodingError {
        let context = DecodingError.Context(codingPath: codingPath, debugDescription: "Cannot decode JSONAny")
        return DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONAny.self, context)
    }

    static func encodingError(forValue value: Any, codingPath: [CodingKey]) -> EncodingError {
        let context = EncodingError.Context(codingPath: codingPath, debugDescription: "Cannot encode JSONAny")
        return EncodingError.invalidValue(value, context)
    }

    static func decode(from container: SingleValueDecodingContainer) throws -> Any {
        if let value = try? container.decode(Bool.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Int64.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Double.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            return value
        }
        if container.decodeNil() {
            return JSONNull()
        }
        throw decodingError(forCodingPath: container.codingPath)
    }

    static func decode(from container: inout UnkeyedDecodingContainer) throws -> Any {
        if let value = try? container.decode(Bool.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Int64.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Double.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decodeNil() {
            if value {
                return JSONNull()
            }
        }
        if var container = try? container.nestedUnkeyedContainer() {
            return try decodeArray(from: &container)
        }
        if var container = try? container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self) {
            return try decodeDictionary(from: &container)
        }
        throw decodingError(forCodingPath: container.codingPath)
    }

    static func decode(from container: inout KeyedDecodingContainer<JSONCodingKey>, forKey key: JSONCodingKey) throws -> Any {
        if let value = try? container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: key) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Int64.self, forKey: key) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Double.self, forKey: key) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: key) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decodeNil(forKey: key) {
            if value {
                return JSONNull()
            }
        }
        if var container = try? container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: key) {
            return try decodeArray(from: &container)
        }
        if var container = try? container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self, forKey: key) {
            return try decodeDictionary(from: &container)
        }
        throw decodingError(forCodingPath: container.codingPath)
    }

    static func decodeArray(from container: inout UnkeyedDecodingContainer) throws -> [Any] {
        var arr: [Any] = []
        while !container.isAtEnd {
            let value = try decode(from: &container)
            arr.append(value)
        }
        return arr
    }

    static func decodeDictionary(from container: inout KeyedDecodingContainer<JSONCodingKey>) throws -> [String: Any] {
        var dict = [String: Any]()
        for key in container.allKeys {
            let value = try decode(from: &container, forKey: key)
            dict[key.stringValue] = value
        }
        return dict
    }

    static func encode(to container: inout UnkeyedEncodingContainer, array: [Any]) throws {
        for value in array {
            if let value = value as? Bool {
                try container.encode(value)
            } else if let value = value as? Int64 {
                try container.encode(value)
            } else if let value = value as? Double {
                try container.encode(value)
            } else if let value = value as? String {
                try container.encode(value)
            } else if value is JSONNull {
                try container.encodeNil()
            } else if let value = value as? [Any] {
                var container = container.nestedUnkeyedContainer()
                try encode(to: &container, array: value)
            } else if let value = value as? [String: Any] {
                var container = container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self)
                try encode(to: &container, dictionary: value)
            } else {
                throw encodingError(forValue: value, codingPath: container.codingPath)
            }
        }
    }

    static func encode(to container: inout KeyedEncodingContainer<JSONCodingKey>, dictionary: [String: Any]) throws {
        for (key, value) in dictionary {
            let key = JSONCodingKey(stringValue: key)!
            if let value = value as? Bool {
                try container.encode(value, forKey: key)
            } else if let value = value as? Int64 {
                try container.encode(value, forKey: key)
            } else if let value = value as? Double {
                try container.encode(value, forKey: key)
            } else if let value = value as? String {
                try container.encode(value, forKey: key)
            } else if value is JSONNull {
                try container.encodeNil(forKey: key)
            } else if let value = value as? [Any] {
                var container = container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: key)
                try encode(to: &container, array: value)
            } else if let value = value as? [String: Any] {
                var container = container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self, forKey: key)
                try encode(to: &container, dictionary: value)
            } else {
                throw encodingError(forValue: value, codingPath: container.codingPath)
            }
        }
    }

    static func encode(to container: inout SingleValueEncodingContainer, value: Any) throws {
        if let value = value as? Bool {
            try container.encode(value)
        } else if let value = value as? Int64 {
            try container.encode(value)
        } else if let value = value as? Double {
            try container.encode(value)
        } else if let value = value as? String {
            try container.encode(value)
        } else if value is JSONNull {
            try container.encodeNil()
        } else {
            throw encodingError(forValue: value, codingPath: container.codingPath)
        }
    }

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        if var arrayContainer = try? decoder.unkeyedContainer() {
            self.value = try JSONAny.decodeArray(from: &arrayContainer)
        } else if var container = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self) {
            self.value = try JSONAny.decodeDictionary(from: &container)
        } else {
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            self.value = try JSONAny.decode(from: container)
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        if let arr = self.value as? [Any] {
            var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
            try JSONAny.encode(to: &container, array: arr)
        } else if let dict = self.value as? [String: Any] {
            var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self)
            try JSONAny.encode(to: &container, dictionary: dict)
        } else {
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            try JSONAny.encode(to: &container, value: self.value)
        }
    }
}
```

I really don't understand why the loading of the `JSON` data is not carried out and therefore automatically returns me my `fatal error` that I entered

Comment: Please replace `try?` with `try` wrapped in a `do - catch` block and `print(error)`. This kind of `fatalError` is pointless. And `JSONAny` is – in terms of performance –  a horrible attempt to support `Any`. I guess traditional `JSONSerializtion` is more efficient in this case.

Comment: @vadian So you advise me not to use app.quicktype.io to generate the code?

Comment: Not necessarily, but you should specify the **real** types for the empty arrays instead of `JSONAny`. My primary advice is to `catch` the error.

Comment: @vadian That JSONAny is a class that has implemented app.quicktype.io in the code.. the only way to make everything different would be to manually create all the template structure right? instead... Can you help me with my question?

Comment: What would the type of `education_experiences` be if it were filled out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works fine. Notice that I use the QuickType.io code but replaced the JSONAny type with String. That may or may not work depending on what the actual types are when those arrays have values in them...

Also note, doing this sort of thing in a playground first before putting it in your actual code is a great way to make sure you are coding/decoding correctly.

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let profileV2: ProfileV2
}

struct ProfileV2: Codable {
    let name: Name
    let emails: Emails
    let birthday: Birthday
    let gender: Gender
    let previousNames, otherNames: [String]
    let currentCity, hometown: CurrentCity
    let relationship: Relationship
    let educationExperiences: [String]
    let workExperiences: [WorkExperience]
}

struct Birthday: Codable {
    let year, month, day: Int
}

struct CurrentCity: Codable {
    let name: String
    let timestamp: Int
}

struct Emails: Codable {
    let emails, previousEmails: [String]
    let pendingEmails, adAccountEmails: [String]
}

struct Gender: Codable {
    let genderOption, pronoun: String
}

struct Name: Codable {
    let fullName, firstName, middleName, lastName: String
}

struct Relationship: Codable {
    let status: String
    let timestamp: Int
}

struct WorkExperience: Codable {
    let employer, title, location, description: String
    let startTimestamp, timestamp: Int
}

let data = """
{
  "profile_v2": {
    "name": {
      "full_name": "test test",
      "first_name": "test",
      "middle_name": "",
      "last_name": "test"
    },
    "emails": {
      "emails": [
        "test@icloud.com"
      ],
      "previous_emails": [
        "test.50@facebook.com"
      ],
      "pending_emails": [
      ],
      "ad_account_emails": [
      ]
    },
    "birthday": {
      "year": 33,
      "month": 33,
      "day": 24
    },
    "gender": {
      "gender_option": "MALE",
      "pronoun": "MALE"
    },
    "previous_names": [
    ],
    "other_names": [
    ],
    "current_city": {
      "name": "test",
      "timestamp": 0
    },
    "hometown": {
      "name": "test",
      "timestamp": 0
    },
    "relationship": {
      "status": "",
      "timestamp": 1574556291
    },
    "education_experiences": [

    ],
    "work_experiences": [
      {
        "employer": "test test test test",
        "title": "test",
        "location": "test test test",
        "description": "",
        "start_timestamp": 1246442400,
        "timestamp": 1589226310
      }
    ]
  }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

do {
    let foo = try decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: data)
    print(foo)
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your suggestion indeed it is correct..
I changed my code a bit using a complete json file (the one in my question was just a part of the `json` file and apparently I have a problem with the variable `profile_uri`  because to make it work I must necessarily specify that it is of type String? and not String

I don't understand why I have to enter the optional

In ` JSON` file `profile_uri`  contains `profile_uri": "https://www.facebook.com/user.user.50`

Comment: Apparently, it doesn't always contain a string. Sometimes it is either missing or it contains null. Since it is optional in the json, it must be optional in Swift.

Comment: And if it's supposed to be a url, you should use `URL?` instead of `String?`

Comment: Thank you but so if I had to figure out if it can be `NULL`  or not empty how can I figure it out by just examining the `JSON file` ? It is not possible?

Also once I have `let foo = try decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: data)`. the constant `foo` which contains all elements of the `JSON file`  how can I use it?

Creating an `array`   that contains the elements of foo doesn't seem like a good idea to me as in this case I have to get the values ​​of the JSON individually

Comment: You have to look at the json and see if some objects are missing the `profile_url` or have it but it says `"profile_url": null`. As for how to work with `foo`... It's a struct. You work with it like you would *any* struct. I suggest you go ahead and accept this answer, then ask a new question if you have one.

Comment: I understand I was thinking of creating a class manager and in its init decode the file and then recall the data with a variable but this approach does not seem right